# Auth::user() Trying to get property of non-object when test REST API from Postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

When I am testing my REST API from postman, it gives me error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Because there is no session in postman. If there is browser then session is created but not in postman. Can anyone give alternate solutions of `Auth::user()`

This is my route

> Route::post('playlist/{id}/follow', 'PlaylistController@follow');

This is my code snippet.

```
public function follow($id)
{
     $user = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
     if ($user->id != Auth::user()->id) {
          Auth::user()->followedUsers()->attach($id);
     }
}
```

Comment: are you protecting your route with `auth:api`?

Comment: No, I didn't protecting.

Comment: can you clarify would you like to use `api` session or `web` session ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use api session.

Comment: you need that to have the Auth middleware taking care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column named `api_token` in your `User` table and add all the route under the middleware `auth:api`.

Then try by sending the `api_token` value from postman in `Headers` like -

```
Authorization Bearer: <api_token_here>
```

`Authorization` is the header name and its value is `Bearer: <api_token_here>`

Then your `Auth::user()->id` will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your fucntion like this :
(i assume that your model is User)

```
 public function follow(User $id)
    {
         if ($id->id != Auth::user()->id) {
              Auth::user()->followedUsers()->attach($id);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Why down vote? you mistake is here `$this->model->findOrFail($id)` Your function does not now in which model you refer to

Comment: Postman does not create any session that's why this error is occured. So, buddy I just want alternate solution of Auth::user(), because Auth::user() does not work when we test our api frrom postman.